# Override count (or whatever) in a SPECIFIC array

Tags: arrays, swift, enumeration

Say you have

```
class Blah {
}
```

and then I'm going to have `[Blah]`

However, the Blah array is going to work a bit differently from a normal array.

For example, I want `count` to work like this, say

```
override count {
  c = super.count // an ordinary count of the array
  y = count of items where blah.color = yellow
  return y
}
```

Of course, I know how to override count (or whatever) by subclassing the appropriate array concept in Swift.

But how can I override count "only in" the array `[Blah]` ... is that possible?

Use case - maybe there's a better way - Blah has a number of concrete subtypes A:Blah, B:Blah .. F:Blah  I want to filter [Blah] so it only returns certain of them (say, "B and D types only") when you enumerate, and the count, etc, would only be for the turned-on subtypes.  I appreciate Swift's slice and so on could be relevant here.

Comment: Even if you *could* override `count` for a given type of array (an `Array` is a `struct`, so no subclassing), it wouldn't be a great idea to change the meaning of such a well established concept. It would break *all sorts* of things, e.g `for index in 0..<array.count`.

Comment: @Hamish is right, overriding `count` is probably not a good idea, now for the 'whatever' part maybe a type constraint on an `Array` would help. Something like `extension Array where Element: Blah`

Comment: Agreed with Andrew's answer below. Just be explicit; don't try to make this magic. That said, it is possible to do with magic, but you have to use the ObjC runtime. You would ISA-swizzle the object (i.e. the same thing KVO does). You generate a new class (that's a subclass of the "real" class), add the `count` implementation you want, and then swap the ISA pointer (`object_setClass`). But wow, you should never do this… :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like people are commenting, you don't really want to override count. Here's some code that shows why that's not going to work and gives another possible solution.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

class Blah {

    let include: Bool

    init(include: Bool) {
        self.include = include
    }

}

// This code "works", but you'll get an error that "count" is ambiguous because
// it's defined in two places, and there's no way to specify which one you want
//extension Array where Element: Blah {
//
//    var count: Int {
//        return reduce(0) { result, element in
//            guard element.include else {
//                return result
//            }
//
//            return result + 1
//        }
//    }
//
//}

// But you could add a helper to any blah sequence that will filter the count for you
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element: Blah {

    var includedBlahCount: Int {
        return reduce(0) { result, blah in
            guard blah.include else {
                return result
            }

            return result + 1
        }
    }

}

let blahs = [Blah(include: false), Blah(include: true)]
print(blahs.count) // 2
print(blahs.includedBlahCount) // 1
```